# Accessing a char array from another class

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working on a crossword puzzle game. In order to set the letters in my tiles, I have a script attached to text components that accessing a char array that stores my letters. It looks like this:

First class:

```
  public class GenerateBoard : MonoBehaviour
  {
    public static char[,]gameBoard = new char[15,15];
    void Start()
    {
        gameBoard[0, 0] = 'W';
    }
```

Second class:

```
public class SetLetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text letter;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        letter = GetComponent<Text>();
        letter.text = GenerateBoard.gameBoard[x,y] + "";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("glitch: " + GenerateBoard.gameBoard[0, 0]);
    }
}
```

I would expect Debug.Log to print 'W' but it appears to be empty. Why isn't it accessing the letter 'W' from the first class? When I use Debug.Log in my first class it properly prints 'W'.

Comment: Did you create the gameobject before running the script with the log? Also, why does it have to be a static char array? Just pass the board component from the gameobject around using the editor

Comment: Both scripts are run as soon as the game is started. But because Debug.Log is in update I figured it would be ran after gameBoard had been instantiated...

How could I pass a component using the editor?

Comment: You can use public variables inside behaviours and assign the game objects to them from the editor

Comment: Yes @GriffinHines Both scripts run as soon as the game started but Script order is a big thing in Unity, Probably the Second Script has a higher script order so the `Debug.Log` gets called before the first script gets the chance to initialized, Here I am assuming you also attached the first script to GameObject as well

Comment: Have you reviewed existing questions about [ensuring an initialization runs before its values are used](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/161909/39518), so that [they have the desired values already when you try to access them](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/115595/39518)?